# R - Adding dots to map in tmap

Tags: r, dictionary, marker, tmap

My map-making code generates a map based on census data and plots important points as a tm_dots() layer. What I'd like to be able to do is differentiate between the types of dots (e.g. if the location is "Informal" or "Commercial").

```
tm_shape(bristol) + tm_fill("population", palette = "YlOrRd", 
auto.palette.mapping = TRUE, 
  title = "Bristol Population", 
  breaks = c(0,5,10,15,20,25), colorNA = "darkgrey") + tm_borders("grey25",alpha = 0.7, lwd = 0.1) +
  tm_dots("n", size=0.1,col="green", shapeNA = NA, title = "Spaces") + 
  tm_legend(text.size=1,title.size=1.2,position=c("left","top")) + 
  tm_layout(legend.outside = TRUE, legend.outside.position = "bottom", title.snap.to.legend = TRUE)
```

What I'm looking for is essentially:

```
tm_dots("n", size=0.1,col=Classification, shapeNA = NA, title = "Spaces")
```

Adding several tm_dots() layers isn't an option. I also can't rename the dot legend, any advice on that too is appreciated.

[image: Current output]

Thanks for your help!

**Solution**

For future reference, I added `offices` to `bristol` via `left_join`, thus adding the `Classification` variable to the `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`. I was having issues with it displaying NA values despite the `showNA = NA` parameter, but `colorNA = NULL` worked. Final line:
 `tm_dots(size=0.1,col="Classification", palette = "Set1", colorNA = NULL)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `bristol` is a polygon shape (`SpatialPolygonDataFrame` or `sf`), and you want to plot dots in some polygons?

Normally, you would have a variable `Offices`, with two levels `"Informal"` and `"Commercial"`. Then it's just `tm_dots(size = 0.1, col = "Offices")`. If you want to place two dots in one polygons because there are Informal and Commercial offices, then you can use your own approach (and use `xmod` and/or `ymod` for one group to prevent overlap), or create a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` or `sf` object with all offices, and a variable `Offices` with two levels as described above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if there were two points in one polygon the normal tm_dots() wouldn't plot both? I'm thinking I could `left_join` the `Offices` variable to `bristol` on `coordinates` and plot it that way.

Comment: Not very clear what you mean. `tm_dots()` plots a dot for each feature (polygon, point, line). Maybe you could create a reproducible example?

Comment: Thanks for your code, I understand it now. When it plots though it's plotting all the NA values despite me putting `showNA = NA`, any advice?

Comment: `showNA` is just for the legend, but you'll have to set it to `FALSE` If it doens't work, I really advise you to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I updated the main question with the answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, you need to have another tm_shape() for it to work. Still haven't got the title() to appear properly but one step at a time.

```
tm_shape(bristol) + tm_fill("population", palette = "YlOrRd", auto.palette.mapping = TRUE, 
  title = "Bristol Population", 
  breaks = c(0,5,10,15,20,25), colorNA = "darkgrey") + tm_borders("grey25",alpha = 0.7, lwd = 0.1) +
  tm_dots("Informal_Offices", size=0.1,col="green", shapeNA = NA, title = "Informal Offices") + 
  tm_shape(bristol) + tm_dots("Commercial_Offices", size=0.1,col="white",shapeNA=NA, title="Commercial Offices") + 
  tm_legend(text.size=1,title.size=1.2,position=c("left","top")) + 
  tm_layout(legend.outside = TRUE, legend.outside.position = "bottom", title.snap.to.legend = TRUE)
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMhHs.png)